Changing Image Based on What Image is Shown
I have three images-one shown, the other two with display:none.
I'd like, when I press the button, for the script to check which image is currently being displayed and switch to the next image accordingly.
The buttons seem to call to the .js file properly, because the browser console returns the final else log.


function rightImage() {
  var image1 = document.getElementById("stc-parking-map");
  var image2 = document.getElementById("stc-first-floor");
  var image3 = document.getElementById("stc-second-floor");
  var image1Indicator = document.getElementById("directions-image1-indicator");
  var image2Indicator = document.getElementById("directions-image2-indicator");
  var image3Indicator = document.getElementById("directions-image3-indicator");
  if (image1.style.display === "flex") {
    image1.style.display = "none";
    image2.style.display = "flex";
    image1Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.92)";
    image2Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(37,53,81,1.00)";
  } else if (image2.style.display === "flex") {
    image2.style.display = "none";
    image3.style.display = "flex";
    image2Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.92)";
    image3Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(37,53,81,1.00)";
  } else if (image3.style.display === "flex") {
    image3.style.display = "none";
    image1.style.display = "flex";
    image3Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.92)";
    image1Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(37,53,81,1.00)";
  } else {
    console.log("Everything Failed?");
  }
}

function leftImage() {
  const image1 = document.getElementById("stc-parking-map");
  const image2 = document.getElementById("stc-first-floor");
  const image3 = document.getElementById("stc-second-floor");
  const image1Indicator = document.getElementById("directions-image1-indicator");
  const image2Indicator = document.getElementById("directions-image2-indicator");
  const image3Indicator = document.getElementById("directions-image3-indicator");
  if (image1.style.display === "block") {
    image1.style.display = "none";
    image3.style.display = "block";
    image1Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.92)";
    image3Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(37,53,81,1.00)";
  } else if (image3.style.display === "block") {
    image3.style.display = "none";
    image2.style.display = "block";
    image3Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.92)";
    image2Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(37,53,81,1.00)";
  } else if (image2.style.display === "block") {
    image2.style.display = "none";
    image1.style.display = "block";
    image2Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.92)";
    image1Indicator.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(37,53,81,1.00)";
  }
}
/*
CSS (There are some properties that belong to a class, so you'll see things like display:flex missing from containers)
*/

#visit-us-parking-and-directions-content {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.peirce-directions-image {
  width: 100%;
}

#stc-parking-map {
  display: flex;
}

#stc-first-floor {
  display: none;
}

#stc-second-floor {
  display: none;
}

#directions-image-change-button-container,
#directions-image-number-indicator-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.directions-image-number-indicator {
  height: 15px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: rgba(224, 224, 219, 1.00);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
}

.directions-image-number-indicator:first-child {
  border-left: solid;
  border-color: rgba(224, 224, 219, 1.00);
}

#directions-image1-indicator {
  background-color: rgba(37, 53, 81, 1.00);
}

.directions-image-change-button {
  padding: 38px 0 30px 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div id="visit-us-parking-and-directions-container" class="section-container">
  <div id="visit-us-parking-and-directions-content" class="section-content">
    <h2>Parking and Directions</h2>
    <div id="parking-directions-images-container">
      <img id="stc-parking-map" class="peirce-directions-image" src="images/stc-parking-map.png" alt="parking-map">
      <img id="stc-first-floor" class="peirce-directions-image" src="images/stc-first-floor.png" alt="first-floor">
      <img id="stc-second-floor" class="peirce-directions-image" src="images/stc-second-floor.png" alt="second-floor">
      <div id="directions-image-number-indicator-container">
        <div id="directions-image1-indicator" class="directions-image-number-indicator"></div>
        <div id="directions-image2-indicator" class="directions-image-number-indicator"></div>
        <div id="directions-image3-indicator" class="directions-image-number-indicator"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="directions-image-change-button-container">
        <button id="directions-left-image-button" class="directions-image-change-button" onClick="leftImage()">&larr;</button>
        <button id="directions-right-image-button" class="directions-image-change-button" onClick="rightImage()">&rarr;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I've tried block and flex for the image display values. I put logs inside of the ifs at one point to see if it passed the if but failed to change the style-it did not pass the ifs, ever. I've tried both const and var for getting the elements.

The style property only returns inline styles, not styles inherited from CSS. Instead of checking styles, use a class that you toggle.

A similar code I used in my contacts page seemed to work without inline styles. Though, it wasn't for images, it was for a container.
Are you suggesting setting a class that is changed back and forth between, for instance, class="active" & class="inactive"?

None of the if conditions will ever be true. I suspect you had an else block in your other code, which set the styles.

No, the first image is just displayed by default, which is how my header bar operates for it's mobile version.

That's because none of the if conditions are ever true, because they're only checking inline styles. Use getComputedStyle() to get CSS styles.

Instead of hoping that CSS will tell you what is being displayed, you should create JS variables and JS logic to control the state of your page, and then use those variables to set/clear/alter styles.

Here is a good way to solve this problem, this solution can still be improved but is good none the less.
I am basically making an array of the image and the indicator elements. With every button click I iterate over them and check which element has the active class. I then replace the active with the appropriate inactive class. The next step is straightforward since we want the next element to be active (previous in case of left button) so we do i+1 or i-1. But we also don't want to go out of bounds. So when we're at either upper or lower limit I manually reset the value of i to the appropriate value for the next part of the code to run.


const imageElements = [...document.getElementsByClassName('images')]
const imageLen = imageElements.length
const indicatorElements = [...document.getElementsByClassName('indicator')]

function rightImage() {
    for(var i = 0; i<imageLen; i++) {
    let e = imageElements[i]
    if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.classList.replace('active', 'display-none');
      indicatorElements[i].classList.replace('indicator-active', 'indicator-inactive')
      if(i >= imageLen-1) i = -1
      if (imageElements[i + 1]) {
          imageElements[i + 1].classList.replace('display-none', 'active');
          indicatorElements[i + 1].classList.replace('indicator-inactive', 'indicator-active')
      }
      return
    }
  }
}

function leftImage() {
  for(var i = imageLen-1; i>=0; i--) {
    let e = imageElements[i]
    if (e.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.classList.replace('active', 'display-none');
      indicatorElements[i].classList.replace('indicator-active', 'indicator-inactive')
      
      if(i === 0) i = imageLen
      if (imageElements[i - 1]) {
          imageElements[i - 1].classList.replace('display-none', 'active');
          indicatorElements[i - 1].classList.replace('indicator-inactive', 'indicator-active')
      }
      return
    }
  }
}
#visit-us-parking-and-directions-content{
        justify-content:flex-end;
    }
    
    .peirce-directions-image{
        width:100%;
    }
    
    img {
      height: 20rem;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .active {
      display: block;
    }
    .display-none {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .indicator-active {
      background: aqua !important;
    }
    .indicator-inactive {
        background-color: black;
    }
    
    #directions-image-change-button-container,
#directions-image-number-indicator-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.directions-image-number-indicator {
  height: 15px;
  width: 33.33%;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: rgba(224, 224, 219, 1.00);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
}

.directions-image-number-indicator:first-child {
  border-left: solid;
  border-color: rgba(224, 224, 219, 1.00);
}

#directions-image1-indicator {
  /* background-color: rgba(37, 53, 81, 1.00); */
}

.directions-image-change-button {
  padding: 38px 0 30px 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div id="visit-us-parking-and-directions-container" class="section-container">
    <div id="visit-us-parking-and-directions-content" class="section-content">
        <h2>Parking and Directions</h2>
        <div id="parking-directions-images-container">
            <img id="stc-parking-map" class="images active" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/painting-mountain-lake-with-mountain-background_188544-9126.jpg?t=st=1712955997~exp=1712959597~hmac=dc6f6c8ab798a59aa74bc356163dc9ceb6097951cc1aaaea45c6efbc70d1f086&w=2000" alt="">
            <img id="stc-first-floor" class="images display-none" src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/28ECAQiPJZ78hxatLTa7Ts/2f695d869736ae3b0de3e56ceaca3958/free-nature-images.jpg?fit=fill&w=1200&h=630" alt="">
            <img id="stc-second-floor" class="images display-none" src="https://static.desygner.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2022/05/04141642/Free-Stock-Photos-01.jpg" alt="">
            
            <div id="directions-image-number-indicator-container">
                <div id="directions-image1-indicator" class="indicator indicator-active directions-image-number-indicator"></div>
                <div id="directions-image2-indicator" class=" indicator indicator-inactive directions-image-number-indicator"></div>
                <div id="directions-image3-indicator " class="indicator indicator-inactive directions-image-number-indicator"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="directions-image-change-button-container">
                <button id="directions-left-image-button" class="directions-image-change-button" onClick="leftImage()">&larr;</button>
                <button id="directions-right-image-button" class="directions-image-change-button" onClick="rightImage()">&rarr;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Thanks! I went with your answer because it seemed closest to my existing code.
I was unaware until your answer that I could assign multiple classes to one element, so that's helpful!
One thing that confuses me though--with my other code that I based my question script off of, it wouldn't run until I had the constants inside of the functions themselves. The same thing happened with your code--your code didn't seem to work until the constants were inside of the functions themselves. Do you know why that may be?
I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver, by the way.

I'm not sure how Adobe Dreamweaver sets up projects such as these. I have always built websites from scratch or with frameworks like Vue/React. All of them would support the code I have written. If you can share more about the project folder structure and how files are imported and used, then perhaps we could help more.

Rather than hide all but one image and have to keep track of which ones to hide/show, the thing to do here is just have only one img element that is always visible and just dynamically change which image is the src.
To do this you put your image paths into an array. That way you can just use the array indices to iterate from one to the next.
You won't have to deal with styles or involved if/then statements.
Here's a simplified example:


const images = ["https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/sm/20180515/sm_5afb099d307d3.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg/2048px-Approve_icon.svg.png", "https://static.thenounproject.com/png/2342715-200.png"]

const img = document.querySelector("img");

let index = 0;


document.querySelector("button.back").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  img.src = images[index--];
  // If at beginning, make back button go to end
  if (index < 0) {index = images.length-1}
});

document.querySelector("button.next").addEventListener("click", function(event){
   // If at end, make back button go to beginning
   if(index === images.length) { index = 0; }
  img.src = images[index++];
});
img {width:200px;}
<button class="back">&lt;</button> <button class="next">&gt;</button>
<br>
<img src="">



